# importing files from a different git repo - Python

Tags: python, git

On my root home directory, I have the following git repositories:

```
/root/foo
/root/foo-lib
```

One python file, let's say `hello.py`, in `/root/foo/scale/hello.py` needs a file from `/root/foo-lib` called `bar.py` (`/root/foo-lib/lib/bar.py`)

Inside `hello.py` I may have:

```
import scale.test as test 
...
```

And many others. However, I need to import the `bar.py` library into that file, which is in a separate repository. How can I accomplish that? I need something like

```
import foo-lib.lib.bar as bar
```

in my `hello.py` file. I'm no sure how to achieve that. Could someone give me a clue?

Comment: Hi,  were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file `/root/__init__.py`, and within `/root/foo/scale/hello.py`, you can use the statement

```
import ...foo-lib.lib.bar as bar
```

Another alternative is to create a symlink within your `/root/foo/scale/` directory, pointing towards `/root/foo-lib`